# How to do an inner join on row number in sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

SQL Server 2008

Two tables:

Table A has following data:

```
RowA
RowB
RowC
RowD
```

Table B has following data:

```
Row4
Row3
Row2
Row1
```

I want to get the following output:

```
RowA Row1
RowB Row2
RowC Row3
RowD Row4
```

The only common value between the two tables is the row number

I can get the data individually of course:

```
SELECT val
FROM A
ORDER BY val

SELECT val
FROM B
ORDER BY val
```

But how do I join on the row number?

And what if I don't have an order-by, but just want the rows in the order they come out?

```
RowA Row4
RowB Row3
RowC Row2
RowD Row1
```

as in the join of

```
SELECT val
FROM A

SELECT val
FROM B
```

Comment: Mind you: as long as you don't explicitly specify an `ORDER BY`, the order in which the rows are returned from the table(s) is **not guaranteed**. It could be different tomorrow ... so linking two rows from two different tables based **solely** on their "ordinal" position in a more or less random output sequence is not reproducible and not reliable. If your two tables don't have anything in common - basically, you cannot really "connect" two datasets from either table...

Comment: I realise that, but in my real life case, the two tables are from functions and will always be in the same order

Answer (score 57, accepted):

try this:

USE [ROW_NUMBER()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186734.aspx) function in sql server 2008

```
select A.val,B.val 
from(
    SELECT val,row_number() over (order by val) as row_num
    FROM A)A
join
    (SELECT val,row_number() over (order by val) as row_num
    FROM B)B
on  A.row_num=B.row_num
ORDER BY A.val,B.val
```

## [SQL fiddle demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/9e5bf/2)

Comment: That's looking like a good start, however what about if I have no order-by

Comment: @Graham: you can give order by (select 0), because order by clause is mandatory there.. see here http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/9e5bf/5

Comment: It's absolutely blowing my mind how this simple operation is not already implemented somehow.

Comment: The row number isn't accurate if you have a JOIN clause in your sub-queries.

Answer (score 0):

```
select A.sectionname, A.Basicprice,A.Brand,A.Description,A.Description,A.Grandtotal,A.GST,A.Gstvalue,A.Hsncode,A.Image,A.Installationcharge,A.Model,B.Age,B.Mark,B.Name,B.class

from(
   SELECT Class,row_number() over (order by class) as row_num,Age,Mark,Name
   FROM classtable)B
   LEFT join
   (SELECT sectionname,row_number() over (order by sectionname) as row_num,Basicprice,Brand,Description,Grandtotal,GST,Gstvalue,Hsncode,Image,Installationcharge,Model
   FROM testtable)A

on  A.row_num=B.row_num
```

Comment: Isn't that basically the same as the (accepted) anwer above?