# SQL Server Join unequal number of rows

Tags: sql-server

I have data like the below, and would like to see results like below.
The blank spaces should be present in the results. Either Table 2 or Table 3 may contain more rows than the other, and blanks/or/nulls should be in the result.

Table 1

```
C1=29 (pk)  C2=4133     
C1=33 (pk)  C2=9375
```

Table 2

```
C1=29(fk)   C2=Adam     
C1=29(fk)   C2=Bob      
C1=29(fk)   C2=Chris        
C1=29(fk)   C2=Dave     
C1=33(fk)   C2=Eddie        
C1=33(fk)   C2=Frank
```

Table 3

```
C1=29(fk)   C2=Helen        
C1=29(fk)   C2=Joice        
C1=33(fk)   C2=Karen        
C1=33(fk)   C2=Laura        
C1=33(fk)   C2=Mary
```

Desired result

```
1.C1=29 1.C2=4133   2.C2=Adam   3.C2=Helen
1.C1=29 1.C2=4133   2.C2=Bob    3.C2=Joice
1.C1=29 1.C2=4133   2.C2=Chris  
1.C1=29 1.C2=4133   2.C2=Dave   
1.C1=33 1.C2=9375   2.C2=Eddie  3.C2=Karen
1.C1=33 1.C2=9375   2.C2=Frank  3.C2=Laura
1.C1=33 1.C2=9375               3.C2=Mary
```

Rohit-s query gives --

```
SELECT t1.col1, t1.col2, t2.col2, t3.col2
FROM dbo.Table1 t1
LEFT JOIN dbo.Table2 t2 ON t1.col1 = t2.col1
LEFT JOIN dbo.Table3 t3 ON t1.col1 = t3.col1

col1    col2    col2    col2
29  4133    Adam    Helen
29  4133    Adam    Joice
29  4133    Bob Helen
29  4133    Bob Joice
29  4133    Chris   Helen
29  4133    Chris   Joice
29  4133    Dave    Helen
29  4133    Dave    Joice
33  9375    Eddie   Karen
33  9375    Eddie   Laura
33  9375    Eddie   Mary
33  9375    Frank   Karen
33  9375    Frank   Laura
33  9375    Frank   Mary
```

[SQL FIDDLE LINK](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/7a15b9/2)

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to do an inner join on row number in sql server](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12972320/how-to-do-an-inner-join-on-row-number-in-sql-server)

Comment: The second edit should give you what you expect.

Comment: @Rohit - not a dupe of cited item, because my example has unequal length of Table2 and Table3, sometimes one is longer than the other and visa versa.

Comment: The 4th edit should do you can check it out in the fiddle link provided.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can't you just `LEFT JOIN` all the tables?

Eg:

```
SELECT t1.C1, t1.C2,t2.C2, t3.C2
FROM Table1 t1
LEFT JOIN Table2 t2 ON t1.C1 = t2.C1
LEFT JOIN Table3 t3 on t1.C1 = t3.C1
```

**EDIT :** 
*Based on your edit, and hoping things are ordered:*

```
SELECT t1.C1, t1.C2, t2.C2, t3.C2
FROM Table1 t1
LEFT JOIN (
             SELECT C1, C2, row_number() OVER (ORDER BY C1, C2) AS row_num
             FROM Table2
          ) t2 ON t1.C1 = t2.C1
LEFT JOIN (
             SELECT C1, C2, row_number() OVER (ORDER BY C1, C2) AS row_num
             FROM Table3
          ) t3 ON t1.C1 = t3.C1 AND t3.row_num = t2.row_num
```

**EDIT 2 :**
*Assuming everything is in order, (Row_Number and Dense_Rank):*

```
SELECT t1.C1, t1.C2, t2.C2, t3.C2
FROM Table1 t1
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT C1, C2, DENSE_RANK() OVER (
            ORDER BY C1
            ) AS group_num, row_number() OVER (
            PARTITION BY C1 ORDER BY C1, C2
            ) AS row_num
    FROM Table2
    ) t2 ON t1.C1 = t2.C1
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT C1, C2, DENSE_RANK() OVER (
            ORDER BY C1
            ) AS group_num, row_number() OVER (
            PARTITION BY C1 ORDER BY C1, C2
            ) AS row_num
    FROM Table3
    ) t3 ON t1.C1 = t3.C1 AND t3.group_num = t2.group_num AND t3.row_num = t2.row_num
```

**EDIT 3:**
*Dense_Rank, Row_Number, Union*

```
SELECT t1.C1 AS T1C1, t1.C2 AS T1C2, t2.C2 AS T2C2, t3.C2 AS T3C3
FROM Table1 t1
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT C1, C2, DENSE_RANK() OVER (
            ORDER BY C1
            ) AS group_num, row_number() OVER (
            PARTITION BY C1 ORDER BY C1, C2
            ) AS row_num
    FROM Table2
    ) t2 ON t1.C1 = t2.C1
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT C1, C2, DENSE_RANK() OVER (
            ORDER BY C1
            ) AS group_num, row_number() OVER (
            PARTITION BY C1 ORDER BY C1, C2
            ) AS row_num
    FROM Table3
    ) t3 ON t1.C1 = t3.C1 AND t3.group_num = t2.group_num AND t3.row_num = t2.row_num

UNION

SELECT t1.C1, t1.C2, t2.C2, t3.C2
FROM Table1 t1
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT C1, C2, DENSE_RANK() OVER (
            ORDER BY C1
            ) AS group_num, row_number() OVER (
            PARTITION BY C1 ORDER BY C1, C2
            ) AS row_num
    FROM Table3
    ) t3 ON t1.C1 = t3.C1
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT C1, C2, DENSE_RANK() OVER (
            ORDER BY C1
            ) AS group_num, row_number() OVER (
            PARTITION BY C1 ORDER BY C1, C2
            ) AS row_num
    FROM Table2
    ) t2 ON t1.C1 = t2.C1 AND t3.group_num = t2.group_num AND t3.row_num = t2.row_num
ORDER BY T1C1, T1C2, T2C2, T3C3
```

**EDIT 4 :** 
*Dense_Rank, Row_Number, Union, SubQuery, Order By*

```
SELECT *
FROM (
        SELECT t1.Col1 AS T1C1, t1.Col2 AS T1C2, t2.Col2 AS T2C2, t3.Col2 AS T3C3
        FROM Table1 t1
        LEFT JOIN (
            SELECT Col1, Col2, DENSE_RANK() OVER (
                    ORDER BY Col1
                    ) AS group_num, row_number() OVER (
                    PARTITION BY Col1 ORDER BY Col1, Col2
                    ) AS row_num
            FROM Table2
            ) t2 ON t1.Col1 = t2.Col1
        LEFT JOIN (
            SELECT Col1, Col2, DENSE_RANK() OVER (
                    ORDER BY Col1
                    ) AS group_num, row_number() OVER (
                    PARTITION BY Col1 ORDER BY Col1, Col2
                    ) AS row_num
            FROM Table3
            ) t3 ON t1.Col1 = t3.Col1 
                 AND t3.group_num = t2.group_num 
                 AND t3.row_num = t2.row_num

        UNION

        SELECT t1.Col1, t1.Col2, t2.Col2, t3.Col2
        FROM Table1 t1
        LEFT JOIN (
            SELECT Col1, Col2, DENSE_RANK() OVER (
                    ORDER BY Col1
                    ) AS group_num, row_number() OVER (
                    PARTITION BY Col1 ORDER BY Col1, Col2
                    ) AS row_num
            FROM Table3
            ) t3 ON t1.Col1 = t3.Col1
        LEFT JOIN (
            SELECT Col1, Col2, DENSE_RANK() OVER (
                    ORDER BY Col1
                    ) AS group_num, row_number() OVER (
                    PARTITION BY Col1 ORDER BY Col1, Col2
                    ) AS row_num
            FROM Table2
            ) t2 ON t1.Col1 = t2.Col1 
                 AND t3.group_num = t2.group_num 
                 AND t3.row_num = t2.row_num
        ) AS SUB
ORDER BY T1C1, T1C2
, CASE WHEN T2C2 IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
, CASE WHEN T3C3 IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
```

[SQL Fiddle Link](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/7a15b9/14)

Comment: See my version of your query, and its results -- edited into my original request.

Comment: How is the computer or any one other you figure out whether adam should join to helen or joice?

Comment: I have created  http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/7a15b9/2  for you to use. I tried your 1st Edit and it did not get all the rows.  Edit2 fails to get last row of Mary.  Edit3  WORKS, but  'null'  Mary   sorts above the others. I think of the two columns of names as independent ascending lists, and after one list ends then the other one continues. Thanks for the great effort and many examples.

Comment: @donPablo - Fixed that as well. But I really think you are too much dependent on the values in the columns which is not really good.

Comment: Thanks for the clever fix with the Case in the OrderBy.  I have no dependency on the values in the columns, just that T2C2 and T3C3 be in ascending sequence, with Nulls/blanks coming at the end.