# Split the table and perform joining without common column

Tags: sql, sql-server, azure, join

The table data looks like the below :

**INPUT :**

```
version value  code   type     year
PMS    0.00    01    HOURS     2006
000    312.00  01    HOURS     2006
000    0.00    04    HOURS     2006
PMS    0.00    01    NON STOCK 2006
000    835.00  01    NON STOCK 2006
000    835.00  04    NON STOCK 2006
000    0.00    04    HOURS     2007
```

I need to split the table based on code(01 and 04) and get the corresponding data then join both results. so my output should look like below

**EXPECTED OUTPUT** :

```
 version value  code   type      year   version value  code    type      year
  PMS    0.00    01    HOURS     2006   000      0.00    04    HOURS     2006
  000    312.00  01    HOURS     2006   000      835.00  04    NON STOCK 2006
  PMS    0.00    01    NON STOCK 2006   000      0.00    04    HOURS     2007
  000    835.00  01    NON STOCK 2006   null     null   null   null      null
```

I tried row_num method by following this post
[How join two tables using SQL without a common column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32081224/how-join-two-tables-using-sql-without-a-common-column)

but my output was like this :

```
version value  code   type      year   version value  code    type      year
  PMS    0.00    01    HOURS     2006   000      0.00    04    HOURS     2006
  000    312.00  01    HOURS     2006   000      835.00  04    NON STOCK 2006
```

I'm using Azure databricks(SQL-Server)

Thanks in advance !!

Comment: Yip, but we need to see your actual query, not just a reference to a question that helped you.

Comment: Put everything needed to ask your question in your post. Give just what you need & relate it to your problem. Don't expect us to read something elsewhere or to guess what part is relevant how. PS Please avoid thanks, etc.

Comment: Please in code questions give a [mre]--cut & paste & runnable code; example input with desired & actual output (including verbatim error messages); tags & versions; clear specification & explanation. For errors that includes the least code you can give that is code that you show is OK extended by code that you show is not OK. (Debugging fundamental.) For SQL include DDL & tabular initialization code. When you get a result you don't expect, pause your overall goal, chop to the 1st subexpression with unexpected result & say what you expected & why, justified by documentation. [ask] [Help]

Comment: You did not even explain the data matching rules. From the example given it is not obvious (at least to me) why and how this row is matched "000    312.00  01    HOURS     2006   000      835.00  04    NON STOCK 2006"

Answer (score 1):

I'm using SQL Server so I think this applies to the data-brick implementation.

Basically I have created 2 derived tables (I wrote 2 queries to give the row_number value per code) and then did a left join on those to give the result that matches your sample

```
declare @input table (version nvarchar(max), value nvarchar(max), code nvarchar(max), type nvarchar(max), year int);

insert @input (version, value, code, type, year)
values
('PMS', '0.00', '01', 'HOURS', 2006),
('000', '312.00', '01', 'HOURS', 2006),
('000', '0.00', '04', 'HOURS', 2006),
('PMS', '0.00', '01', 'NON STOCK', 2006),
('000', '835.00', '01', 'NON STOCK', 2006),
('000', '835.00', '04', 'NON STOCK', 2006),
('000', '0.00', '04', 'HOURS', 2007)


select *
from @input; /*original data*/

select *
from /*desired output*/
(
    select ROW_NUMBER() over(order by code) as id, *
    from @input
    where code = '01'
) a
left join
(
    select ROW_NUMBER() over(order by code) as id, *
    from @input
    where code = '04'
) b on a.id = b.id;
```

Comment: yes this code helps me . but what incase the number of rows on code = 01 is less and code = 04 is more. will the left join help then?

Comment: The way that left joins work is that you will see everything in the code=01 derived table and only the items in the code=04 derived table that have a corresponding match in the code=01 derived table. We can change the join condition to a "full outer join" if you also need to see everything in the code=04 derived table too?

Comment: full outer join worked