# How to merge tables if they don't have a common column in sql?

Tags: sql, oracle, pivot

Supposing I have two tables in Oracle. One of them looks like so:

| Name | Exam | Grade |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Mark | Math | 80 |
| Mark | English | 67 |
| Andrew | Math | 90 |
| Steve | English | 59 |

The other table I have looks like this:

| Mark | Andrew | Steve |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Null | Null | Null |

This is my expected result:

| Mark | Andrew | Steve |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Math-80 | Math-90 | English-59 |
| English-67 | Null | Null |

How would one merge the second table with the first one for it to look like the result above? My main problem is that there are no common columns, and I have to have the values of the first table set as the column names for the second table. I'm really stuck with this one...

Comment: Pivot + all_tab_columns

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use *PIVOT*ing along with *ROW_NUMBER()* Analytic function in order to group the set by each exam per each person such as

```sql
SELECT "Mark", "Andrew", "Steve"
  FROM (SELECT Name,
               Exam || '-' || Grade AS Exam,
               ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY Name ORDER BY Exam DESC) AS rn
          FROM t1)
 PIVOT (
        MAX(Exam) FOR Name IN ('Mark' AS "Mark",'Andrew' AS "Andrew",'Steve' AS "Steve")
       )
```

where *the second table* is not needed

<kbd>[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_21&fiddle=e05d19f09a7bef8996f00fb14c444058)</kbd>

Answer (score 0):

Use the AS parameter or CROSS JOIN ?

You can also read this : [How join two tables using SQL without a common column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32081224/how-join-two-tables-using-sql-without-a-common-column)

Comment: I gotta merge the tables, as in MERGE function (INSERT, DELETE, UPDATE)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).