# Create Query to join 2 tables 1 on 1 with nothing in common

Tags: sql, sql-server, join

I have a table TAB_1 which has 230 rows.

```
CREATE TABLE TAB_1 (audit_id bigint NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY)
```

I have another table TAB_2 which also has 230 rows.

```
CREATE TABLE TAB_2 (employee_id bigint NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY, first_name varchar(50) NOT NULL, last_name varchar(50) NOT NULL)
```

Both these tables have nothing in common.

I want to write a query which will give me all the columns in these 2 tables 1 on 1 (i.e. 1st row of TAB_1 with 1st row of TAB_2, 2nd row of TAB_1 with 2nd row of TAB_2 and so on). That query will also have 230 rows.

How can I do that?

I tried these queries but they are given result as every row in TAB_1 times every row in TAB_2:

```
select a.audit_id, b.employee_id, b.first_name, b.last_name
from TAB_1 a inner join TAB_2 b on 1 = 1

select a.audit_id, b.employee_id, b.first_name, b.last_name
from TAB_1 a cross join TAB_2 b
```

Comment: join on ROW_NUMBER().

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You need a key to join on.  You can get this using `row_number()`:

```
select t1.*, t2.*
from (select t1.*, row_number() over (order by audit_id) as seqnum
      from tab_1 t1
     ) t1 full outer join
     (select t2.*, row_number() over (order by employee_id) as seqnum
      from tab_2 t2
     ) t2
     on t1.seqnum = t2.seqnum;
```

This assumes that the ordering is based on the first column.  The `full outer join` will return all rows, regardless of whether they have the same number of rows or not.

Answer (score 3):

You don't want to join on "nothing" because you'll end up with a cartesian join -- and that will give you way more than 230 rows. Instead, you want to join on row number. [Here's someone that did it for you already.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12972320/how-to-do-an-inner-join-on-row-number-in-sql-server)

Comment: cartesian join or cross join! learn something everyday... here's a link for those who want to learn more it is exactly what i needed... https://www.tutorialspoint.com/sql/sql-cartesian-joins.htm

Comment: (ps - agree this is not what OP wanted...My use case is different and I actually want n*k rows)

Answer (score 2):

Create two new queries and join them:

These new queries will have a new column: row_number()

Select *, Row_NUMBER() as rowTab1 from TAB_1

Select *, Row_Number() as rowTab2 from Tab_2

Now create a third query containing the previous two views and join on rowTab1  = rowTab2

Answer (score 2):

If you can add and extra column on both tables called for example "joinparameter" and have it go from 1 to 230 and join then both by that maybe that can work.

Something like this:

> select a.audit_id, b.employee_id, b.first_name, b.last_name
>   from TAB_1 a inner join TAB_2 b on a.joinparameter = b.joinparameter

Or if both audit_id and employee_id go from 1 to 230 you can join them