# SQL Server 2008, how to join tables on different attributes

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have two tables like this:

**Table A**:

```
ID VAL
1  10
2  20
3  30
4  40
5  50
```

**Table B**:

```
ID VAL2
sd 50
gh 80 
dv 90
bf 100
ww 45
```

Joined table:

```
ID Val VAL2 
1  10  50
2  20  100
3  30  45
4  40  80
5  50  90
```

So, ID in table A is matched to an ID in table B

```
1 - sd, 2 - bf, 3 - ww, 4 - gh, 5 - dv
```

How can I join these two?

```
select A.ID, A.VAL, B.Val
from tableA A
**left join tableB B on A.ID = B.ID ??**
```

Thank you!

Comment: You need to [join by the rownumber](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12972355/2441442). But you shouldn't do this. Better read about *relational database system* and *normalization* instead.

Comment: How you are assuming 1 - sd, 2 - bf, 3 - ww, 4 - gh, 5 - dv?? any rule here??

Comment: select * into #abc from (select (case when id='sd' then 1 when id='bf' then 2 when id='ww' then 3 when id='gh' then 4 else 5 end) as idd, *  from TableB) b  
   
  select tempabc.idd,a.val,tempabc.val from #abc tempabc join TableA a on a.id=tempabc.idd order by idd

Answer (score 0):

One option here, which does not require the use of a temporary table, would be to create an inline table containing the mappings of table A's ID values to table B's ID values.

```
SELECT t1.ID AS ID
       t1.VAL AS Val,
       t3.VAL2 AS Val2
FROM tableA t1
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT 1 AS IDA, 'sd' AS IDB
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 2 AS IDA, 'bf' AS IDB
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 3 AS IDA, '22' AS IDB
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 4 AS IDA, 'gh' AS IDB
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 5 AS IDA, 'dv' AS IDB
) t2
    ON t1.ID = t2.IDA
INNER JOIN tableB t3
    ON t2.IDB = t3.ID
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT a.ID, a.VAL, B.VAL2 FROM 
(
SELECT CASE WHEN ID = 'sd' THEN 1
WHEN ID = 'bf' THEN 2
WHEN ID =  'ww' THEN 3
WHEN ID = 'gh' THEN 4
WHEN ID = 'dv' THEN 5
END AS ID, VAL2 FROM tableB
) AS t INNER JOIN tableA a ON a.ID = t.Id
```