# Add condition in SQL query with INNER JOIN on ROW_NUMBER

Tags: sql, sql-server, inner-join, row-number

I'm trying to write an `INNER JOIN` with `ROW_NUMBER` but the result of my query is not what i expected.

I'm trying to adapt this query :

```
SELECT TOP 5 *
FROM Details, Application
WHERE Application.ID = Details.ApplicationID 
  AND Details.ApplicationID = 5
```

with `ROW_NUMBER()`.

I used this example [How to do an inner join on row number in sql server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12972320/how-to-do-an-inner-join-on-row-number-in-sql-server)

Now I have this :

```
SELECT TOP 5 * 
FROM
    (SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY Details.ID) AS RowNum 
     FROM Details) A 
JOIN
    (SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY Application.ID) AS RowNum 
     FROM Application) B ON A.RowNum = B.RowNum AND A.RowNum BETWEEN 1 AND 5
```

But I'm trying to add this condition

```
WHERE 
    Application.ID = Details.ApplicationID 
    AND Details.ApplicationID = 5
```

inside my new query, can someone give me some help please?

Can I add a `WHERE` inside my query?

PS: I'm using SQL Server 2008

Comment: `TOP/LIMIT` without `ORDER BY` does not make any sense most of the time.

Comment: Hi. Add it how exactly? If you don't say then why do you think we can tell you how to add it? How do we know what you expected if you don't tell us? What is the query with unexpected behaviour? Please read & act on [mcve]. That includes using words to explain what you want your query to return & giving a cut & paste & runnable example. Also the answer is going to be very basic. What did you find researching? What did you try? Please read [ask] & the downvote arrow mouseover text.

Comment: I'm just asking if i can add a "WHERE" inside my current query

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : using old-style JOINs](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins) - that old-style *comma-separated list of tables* style was replaced with the *proper* ANSI `JOIN` syntax in the ANSI-**92** SQL Standard (**25 years** ago) and its use is discouraged

Comment: Added back the `MySQL` tag, because your original question, which I completely answered, was about MySQL, not SQL Server.

Comment: Sorry, I could not find any reference of MySQL in the history. Do not tag as MySQL. The second revision clearly contains SQL Server.

Comment: @Q.Rey . . . Your question was originally mistagged and Tim answered that question.  The tag significantly changes the question.  To be honest, though, I don't understand the new version.  I would suggest that you ask *another* question, provide sample data and desired results.  You might also address the lack of `ORDER BY` with `TOP` as well.

Answer (score 2):

MySQL has a direct analogue to SQL Server's `TOP`; it is `LIMIT`, and it behaves the same way:

```
SELECT *
FROM Details d
INNER JOIN Application a
     ON a.ID = d.ApplicationID AND d.ApplicationID = 5
ORDER BY some_col
LIMIT 5;
```

Note that it doesn't make much sense to use `LIMIT` (or `TOP`) without an `ORDER BY` clause.  This is because you haven't told the database *which* order you want to use when choosing the first 5 records.

Also, I converted your implicit old-school join to a modern, explicit, inner join.  This is the preferred way of writing joins now.

Comment: But can I add BETWEEN in my query? Because i need it to paginate my table

Comment: Pagination is a totally different topic, which didn't come out in your question above.  You may want to ask a new question if you have a big follow up point.

Comment: wait what? It is tagged SQL Server.

Comment: @SalmanA The OP changed the question.  Check the revision history :-)