# Join two tables row by row

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I have two tables

```
 Col1  COl2  COl3  Col4
    1          3     
    3          5      
    4          6
```

and second table is also the same

```
Col11  COl21  COl31  Col41
  1            3     
  3            5      
  4            6
```

I want to go row by row and produce an output as below

```
Col11  Col21       COl31  Col41
 1     Col1/Col11    3    Col3/Col31
 3     Col1/Col11    5     ..
 4     Col1/Col11    6     ....
```

I could do an inner join and find matching records but in this case I don't have any column to match to and I just want to go row by row and calculate it.. Can someone please tell me how I can achieve this.

Comment: The query you showed us does not seem to line up with the sample data.  Please tidy up your question.

Comment: This is unclear. Query vs sample data, and those `Col1/Col11` don't really say much.

Comment: SQL tables represent *unordered* sets.  There is no ordering unless a column specifies the ordering.   Your tables do not seem to have such a column, so there is no way to do what you want.  It would *seem* that the first and third columns do this, but you explicitly say they don't.

Comment: Got it..Thanks Gordon

Comment: Seems to be a duplicate of this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12972320/how-to-do-an-inner-join-on-row-number-in-sql-server . However, do note that results WILL be random without ordering

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
DECLARE @Tab1 AS TABLE (Col1 INT,COl2 INT,  COl3 INT,  Col4 INT)
INSERT INTO @TAb1
SELECT 1,NULL,3,NULL UNION ALL     
SELECT 3,NULL,5,NULL UNION ALL      
SELECT 4,NULL,6,NULL 

DECLARE @Tab2 AS TABLE (Col11 INT,COl21 INT,  COl31 INT,  Col41 INT)
INSERT INTO @TAb2
SELECT 1,NULL,3,NULL UNION ALL     
SELECT 3,NULL,5,NULL UNION ALL      
SELECT 4,NULL,6,NULL 

;WITH CTE
AS
(
SELECT Col11,'Col11'AS COl21  ,COl31 ,'COl31' AS Col41 
FROM @Tab2   
UNION ALL
SELECT Col1,'Col1' ,COl3,'COl3' 
FROM @Tab1
)
    SELECT  
    Col11,
    STUFF((SELECT DISTINCT '/'+COl21 FROM CTE i WHERE i.Col11=o.Col11
        FOR XML PATH ('')),1,1,'') As COl21,
    COl31,
    STUFF((SELECT DISTINCT '/'+Col41 FROM CTE i WHERE i.COl31=o.COl31
        FOR XML PATH ('')),1,1,'') As Col41 
FROM CTE o
GROUP BY Col11,COl31
```

Result

```
Col11    COl21      COl31     Col41
----------------------------------------
1       Col1/Col11    3     COl3/COl31
3       Col1/Col11    5     COl3/COl31
4       Col1/Col11    6     COl3/COl31
```