# Why does LEFT JOIN work in this query with rowid but INNER JOIN does not?

Tags: sqlite, join, random, left-join, inner-join

I have a simple table `OriginalValidLeaders` with one column `LeaderType`.

```
Leader A
Leader B
Leader C
```

Now I want to randomly assign them with one another, for example (it's okay if some of them do not swap):

```
Leader A | Leader C
Leader B | Leader A
Leader C | Leader B
```

In [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12972320/how-to-do-an-inner-join-on-row-number-in-sql-server), the solution is to use `row_number()`, however for some reason, my SQLite does not support that, so I tried the following query and it works:

```
SELECT L.LeaderType, R.LeaderType
FROM OriginalValidLeaders L
LEFT JOIN
    (
        SELECT LeaderType
        FROM OriginalValidLeaders
        ORDER BY random()
    ) R
ON L.rowid = R.rowid;
```

However to be honest, it was the result of one of my luck tries, and I do not understand why it works. At first I tried `INNER JOIN` (which make more sense to me) but no result returned.

So my questions are:

- Why does LEFT JOIN works but not INNER JOIN?
- Does this always work for all cases?

---

Testing schema/data (credit to forpas):

```
CREATE TABLE OriginalValidLeaders (LeaderType TEXT);

INSERT INTO OriginalValidLeaders (LeaderType) VALUES
('Leader A'), ('Leader B'), ('Leader C');
```

Comment: You need sqlite 3.25 or newer for window functions like `row_number()`, btw.

Comment: What answer can you expect other than that left join does one thing & inner join does another? How they work is a faq. If you don't tell us what you expect of each case how can we tell you where your beliefs and/or reasoning are wrong or right? Why do you say "it works"? Test cases can't show absence of bugs. ORDER BY does nothing in a subquery without TOP/LIMIT. See [ask] & the voting arrow mouseover texts. PS Learn what LEFT JOIN ON returns: INNER JOIN ON rows UNION ALL unmatched left table rows extended by NULLs. Always know what INNER JOIN you want as part of an OUTER JOIN.

Comment: Please in code questions give a [mcve]--cut & paste & runnable code; example input with desired & actual output (including verbatim error messages); clear specification & explanation. That includes the least code you can give that is code that you show is OK extended by code that you show is not OK. (Debugging fundamental.) PS Tables have no order. Query results have (partial) order.

Comment: @philipxy Sorry and thank you for the info. I rarely ask question on Database so I am not familiar yet. I have added it to the question. I will surely remember that next time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must be using an old version of **SQLite**. 
It's true that the same query (the one with the `LEFT JOIN`) returns different results for different versions:
--------**SQLite 3.8**

```
a        | b       
-------- | -------
Leader A | Leader B
Leader B | Leader C
Leader C | Leader A
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlite_3.8&fiddle=bc8f09124135ff7ee5a5ba4d7d3d445f).
-------**SQLite 3.26**

```
| a        | b   |
| -------- | --- |
| Leader A |     |
| Leader B |     |
| Leader C |     |
```

See the [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/yiTfpZxc7zkhbiyNHkqka/0).
I don't know if this was a bug and is now corrected in newer versions.
In both versions the `INNER JOIN` query does not return any rows.
**But** if you just add to it:

```
ORDER BY L.rowid
```

then it works fine.
See the [demo for 3.8](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlite_3.8&fiddle=1f3333130d11ea832c4fb6a595b67183) and the [demo for 3.26](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/yiTfpZxc7zkhbiyNHkqka/1).
Now, what is the `rowid` of a subquery? 
The truth is that **it exists as a column**, but it is `null`.
See the [demo for 3.8](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlite_3.8&fiddle=2b5510f47f60e6a00902828781c20816) and the [demo for 3.26](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/kVcPvbk8WGAiurHMaKDdYt/0).

Comment: Wow thanks a lot. So turn out it's unintended bug? My `sqlite_version()` is returning 3.15.2. Unfortunately, I am modding a game and upgrading version is out of question.

Comment: And btw, even when result is not returned, if you run COUNT(*) query, it still returns 3, not 0.

Comment: *if you run COUNT(*) query, it still returns 3, not 0* yes it does and also in DB Browser for SQLite if you run the inner join query you can see the indices of the 3 rows but nothing else. I guess it is a bug. I can't explain such behavior.

Comment: Thanks, I have reported [the issue](https://github.com/sqlitebrowser/sqlitebrowser/issues/1892). Will see if it's the DB Browser UI bug or indeed a SQLite bug.